Playwright - type or fill not working as expected
I am automating UI using PlayWright and Java. I have a search box in the iFrame. When I enter the text in it, I get the tool tip: Search for <number_entered> by. However, when I enter the number using PlayWright's .fill() or .type() the UI does not identify the text entered and displays message: Search for "" by (refer below screenshot) implying that the UI thinks no text is entered.

When I enter the same text manually it just works fine. The UI identfies the text entered.
Code:
Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false).setHandleSIGINT(false));
Page page = browser.newPage();
FrameLocator frame = page.frameLocator("#iFrameID");
Locator searchBox = frame.locator("#searchBox");
searchBox.click();
searchBox.fill ("454545487");
Locator searchIcon = frame.locator(".searchContainer");
searchIcon.click()


Java != JavaScript. Please share a [mcve] including the site being automated.

What is the ui there? Can you try blurring and focusing the element to see if it needs a specific event to update? Maybe dispatch an onchange or oninput after fill()

Try using:
await searchBox.pressSequentially('454545487')

This method will emit all the necessary keyboard events, with all the keydown, keyup, keypress events in place. You can even specify the optional delay between the key presses to simulate real user behavior.

I tried .press() and . pressSequentially() both. However, the data entered is still not identified by the UI. With Selenium, UI is able to identify the data entered.

Are you using the selector "#searchBox" in selenium?

Vishal's answer helped to resolve the issue. Apparently, the issue was that PlayWright was typing really quick for my application. Slowing it down lusing below code helped:
searchBox.pressSequentially('454545487', new Locator.PressSequentiallyOptions().setDelay(400));
